# PHP - csv in_array function check

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to pass `if()` statement with `!in_array()` check for the generated `csv` file.

End result is returning **false** for some reason, and I can not find what am I doing wrong. I am trying to pass false statement and continue with code execution.

Input:

- Array with data I want to put into csv file.
- Creating and inputing
  data into file.
- Getting the file

  ```
     $list = [
            0 => [
                'materials'
            ],
            1 => [
                'products'
            ]
        ];

     $testCsvFile = fopen("test.csv", "w");
     foreach ($list as $fields) {
          fputcsv($testCsvFile, $fields);
      }

    $projectRoot = substr(strrchr(getcwd(), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR), 1);
    $getFile = $projectRoot . '/test.csv';
    $file = basename($getFile);

    if ($list && is_array($list)) {
        unset($parsed_data[0]);
    }
    if (!in_array($file, ['materials', 'products'])) {
        return false;
    }

  .... next //
  ```

Comment: `basename()` only returns the name of a file, not its content. To check the content, you need to read the file an parse the content with `fgetcsv()`. Alternatively just trust your own code and take it for granted, that the file has everything you put into it.

Comment: Your `$file = basename($getFile)` result is `test.csv`

Comment: @Justinas Just to clearfy, evan when I put materials.csv it is still the same.

Comment: Or is your problem that you are expecting `basename` to remove the file extension? If so, you need to tell it that explicitly: https://3v4l.org/WFne9

Answer (score 1):

you're searching the strings without reading the file you should first open the file , read it then you should find string in array, I've pasted below code just for your reference which is searching the string in csv file after opening and reading.

```
$file = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$str = "materials";
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    if(in_array($str, $data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $i)
        {
            echo $i."<br>";
        }   
    }
}
fclose($file);
```